# Что значат квадратные скобки после метода в php?

Tags: php, массивы

```
$this->some_model->GetSessions($current_date)['Data']['Sessions']['Session'];
```

Понимаю что вызывают метод GetSessions с параметром $current_date.
А какой смысл квадратных скобок? Это какая-то выборка элементов массива в запросе или ответе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Это какая-то выборка элементов массива в запросе или ответе?

Метод возвращает массив. Всё остальное - выборка из этого самого массива, который возвращает метод

---

```
function test() {
    return [
        'user' => [
            'name' => 'Andrey',
            'contacts' => [
                'email' => 'a@a.ru',
                'phone' => '+79274567788'
            ]
        ]
    ];
}

echo test()['user']['contacts']['phone']; // +79274567788
```

Возможность разыменовывания результата функции появилась в PHP 5.4, ЕМНИП